# How to bundle all dependencies of a file into a single chunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollup

Including everything in a single file is easy, e.g.

```
manualChunks: () => {
  return 'everything';
},
```

However, we have a component `src/components/Chat/index.tsx` that loads a ton of dependencies that are only used by this component. Therefore, I would like to lazy load `src/components/Chat/index.tsx` in our React application, and have all dependencies of this component in a separate chunk.

I tried doing it this way:

```
manualChunks: (id: string) => {
  // Some IDs are not file paths, e.g.
  // 'virtual:vite-plugin-ssr:pageFiles:client:client-routing'
  if (!id.includes(__dirname)) {
    return DEFAULT_CHUNK_NAME;
  }

  // Rollup ID starts with a weird zero-width character that I was not able
  // to remove using trim() or regex.
  const pathStartIndex = id.indexOf('/');

  // Rollup IDs might include search parameters, e.g.
  // 'node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js?commonjs-exports'
  const filePath = path.relative(
    __dirname,
    id.slice(pathStartIndex).split('?')[0]
  );

  if (filePath.includes('src/components/Chat/')) {
    return 'chat';
  }

  return DEFAULT_CHUNK_NAME;
},
```

However, the resulting bundle includes only `src/components/Chat/index.tsx` and all sub-components under `src/components/Chat/`. It did not bundle together any of the dependencies that they use.

Is there a way to determine what dependencies are exclusive to `src/components/Chat/*` and bundle them together?

Comment: hey man, did you find a solution for this, I'm in a similar situation but I can't find any solution on the internet for this